# Belt-mounted remote with ~5 buttons to communicate with Unity application

Tags: remote-control

I need a belt-mounted device with about 5 buttons which can communicate wirelessly with a computer. Specifically, when the user presses a button I need to be able to detect it in my Unity application so I can trigger certain events.

The device will be used while the user is being tracked by a motion capture system (either a Kinect or a mocap suit), so ideally it would be easy to press buttons without the need to look down at it.

Something like a [Wireless Numeric Keypad](http://www.targus.com/us/wireless-numeric-keypad-akp11us) would be ideal on the software side as I'd be able to just treat it like a regular keyboard in Unity, but physically it's larger than I'd like and I don't need nearly that many buttons. It would also require a bit of work to mount on a belt (though that's not much of an issue).

Comment: I wonder if a Wii-mote or a Roku3 remote could be used for such a thing? I know the Wii-mote has windows drivers for it.

Comment: Not quite what I had in mind, but I'll add them to the list of things to consider. It could potentially be useful if the user could point a Wii-mote at the screen to use it as a mouse as well as for the buttons.

Comment: http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Use-a-Wiimote-as-Your-Computers-Mouse/ Thats possible.

Comment: Have you considered a mouse?  Scroll-Up / Scroll Down / Click Scroll / Left Click / Right click.  Also there are a tone of mice with more buttons.

Comment: I hadn't considered a mouse. It would work, but the non-uniform buttons wouldn't be ideal. Currently I'm leaning towards [this](http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/Wireless-Bluetooth-Gamepad-Remote-Controller-For-VR-BOX-PC-Phone-Android-IOS-New-/361869412470?var=&hash=item5441190876:m:mZf0-QKziym8cfCbNoNHv-A.). The button configuration would be pretty good for using it without looking, the joystick could probably be used to control the mouse, and it should be easy to implement in my app.